# Bypassing the GFW with IPv6 and proxying all IPv4 traffic

Tags: firewalls, ipv6, censorship

I hope I'm in the right forum for this kind of question. I'm in China and as you're probably all aware, the Great Firewall (GFW) blocks a lot of websites. Surprisingly, when using the IPv6 connection provided by CERNET (academic university network), I can bypass GFW and access blocked websites such as google, youtube, facebook, twitter, ...

Unfortunately, not all websites support IPv6 yet, so disabling IPv4 is not an option as it makes lots of websites inaccessible (also Skype won't work without IPv4).

Is there an easy way to proxy/tunnel/whatever all IPv4 traffic through my IPv6 connection? I found a website, sixxs.net, that kinda does what I'm searching for, but I'd like to have this functionality on an OS-level (like a VPN).

Any tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for how a client which is effectively IPv6-only can connect to IPv4-only sites. NAT64 is designed to allow IPv6-only clients to connect to IPv4-only servers. In order to use NAT64 you also need to use DNS64 and/or 464XLAT. It is possible for 464XLAT to be autoconfigured using information from DNS64.

There are public NAT64 installs in various places around the internet, sometimes these will also provide a public DNS64. The first showing when I did a search was [this deploy360 page](http://www.internetsociety.org/deploy360/blog/2013/03/open-public-test-of-nat64dns64-at-go6lab/) which lists three DNS64 addresses. Of those `2001:67c:27e4::64` was the only one working for me.

If you configure your device to use `2001:67c:27e4::64` as your DNS server and disable IPv4, you will be able to access IPv4-only sites through the NAT64. You can also do your own search for providers, the one I found is certainly not the only public NAT64+DNS64.

This relies on the client software you use to support IPv6. If you need to use client software without IPv6 support, you need 464XLAT support on your device. 464XLAT will translate IPv4 traffic from the application to IPv6 and send it to the NAT64 which translates it back to IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of mechanisms that are designed to ease the transition from IPv4 to IPv6. There is a good explanation of them [here on the IPv6 website](http://ipv6.com/articles/gateways/IPv6-Tunnelling.htm).

I think that all of the OS's have drivers for all of the main methods that require them. If I look at my own Windows PC network configuration for example using `ipconfig /all`. I can see both an external and internal ISATAP driver configured.

These work at the OS network driver level and so should be transparent.

One of the oldest IPv6 Tunnel Brokers https://tunnelbroker.net/ also has a description [here](https://tunnelbroker.net/) about using brokers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think the tunnelbroker.net website provides the opposite of what I want? "Our free tunnel broker service enables you to reach the IPv6 Internet by tunneling over existing IPv4 connections from your IPv6 enabled host or router to one of our IPv6 routers"